# Barracuda Message Archiver Database Storage Format

Tags: email, database, storage, format, barracuda

I need access to a [Barracuda Message Archiver](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/archiver-overview.php) database so that I can issue queries against it.  The default web-based email search mechanism is not powerful enough to handle complex nested and/or type queries and I need that functionality.  I need either access to the database files to read them directly or to export them to some other database-like format I can issue more complex queries against.  I can write a program/script to do the conversion, if that is necessary.  My client has physical access to the machine but doesn't know much about the the file storage format and access permissions, and I'm not available to get onsite right now, but they might be able to setup VNC/Remote Desktop type access for me.  A Google search didn't turn up anything obvious about the database format they use.  My questions:

- What format is the message database stored in?  I see some hints it is MySQL, but I'm not certain.
- Are there special security issues involved with this brand of hardware (I believe it runs a custom Linux variant), such as encrypted file system, encrypted database, no customer command line access, etc. that might make it harder to get to the files?

Answer (score 0):

I did a bunch of checking, but unfortunately I can't find any information about this.  You might need to dialogue directly with Barracuda developers to find out if you can get at the data this way.